# Use ssh without trying ssh-keys

Tags: ssh, authentication

If I try to connect to a certain server with

```
ssh example.com
```

ssh aborts with `Too many authentication failures` because I have more than 5 ssh keys in my .ssh folder and it loops through all those keys with none of them fitting ([detailed description here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65120/ssh-always-too-many-authentication-failures))

How can I tell ssh not to look in my keys and just give me the password prompt?

Comment: Seems you need: http://serverfault.com/questions/130346/ssh-use-only-my-password-ignore-my-ssh-key-dont-prompt-me-for-a-passphrase

Comment: @rub77. The answer has already been given. You can add your solution and mark it as answer. Glad you solved it.

Comment: I usually use a config file that specifies which key belongs to which server and this negates the need for looping through the keys.

Comment: @DavidKohen can you add a description how to do that here please? [ssh always too many authentication failures](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/65120)

Comment: So this is a duplicate question, please delete this one (since you are asking us to answer in the other question), though I think this is a more fitting site to post this in.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, Here I asked for a workaround. This is of global interest, and doesn't only solve the other question I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following method works:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password host.example.org
```

Comment: Thanks to @val0x00ff for the link: [SSH use only my password, Ignore my ssh key, don't prompt me for a passphrase](http://serverfault.com/q/130346)